# How to build a topological map based on grid map

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, guys

Recently, I successfully built a grid map based on Gmapping algorithm and marked some grids(x,y coordinate value) which I think should be topological node. Then how to build a topological map using these nodes and grid map? Is there a package to solve this.

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134586/how-to-build-a-topological-map-based-on-grid-map/) by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

see this new package:

http://www.ros.org/news/2013/03/new-package-minecraft-ros.html

---

Originally posted by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) with karma: 118 on 2014-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on 2014-03-01**:
Sorry,Sir  I want to build a topological map rather than minecraft world. Many thanks.